# Python: Listing the duplicates in a list

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python and I am interested in listing duplicates within a list. I know how to remove the duplicates ( **set()** ) within a list and how to list the duplicates within a list by using **collections.Counter**; however, for the project that I am working on this wouldn't be the most efficient method to use since the run time would be **n(n-1)/2 --> O(n^2)** and n is anywhere from 5k-50k+ string values.

So, my idea is that since python lists are linked data structures and are assigned to the memory when created that I begin counting duplicates from the very beginning of the creation of the lists.

1. List is created and the first index value is the word 'dog'
2. Second index value is the word 'cat'
3. Now, it would check if the second index is equal to the first index, if it is then append to another list called Duplicates.
4. Third index value is assigned 'dog', and the third index would check if it is equal to 'cat' then 'dog'; since it matches the first index, it is appended to Duplicates.
5. Fourth index is assigned 'dog', but it would check the third index only, and not the second and first, because now you can assume that since the third and second are not duplicates that the fourth does not need to check before, and since the third/first are equal, the search stops at the third index.

My project gives me these values and append it to a list, so I would want to implement that above algorithm because I don't care how many duplicates there are, I just want to know if there are duplicates.

I can't think of how to write the code, but I figured the basic structure of it, but I might be completely off (using random numgen for easier use):

```
for x in xrange(0,10):
    list1.append(x)
    for rev, y in enumerate(reversed(list1)):
        while x is not list1(y):
            cond()
            if ???
```

Comment: I believe lists in (C)Python are over-allocated arrays, not linked lists.

Comment: Why is this going to be O(n^2)? Inserting n elements into a `set` or `Counter` is only O(n); they're both implemented as hash tables. However, the design you came up to improve things actually _is_ O(n^2), because you're explicitly checking n-1 values each time through the loop.

Comment: I had the wrong impression that Python lists were single linked lists pointed and assigned to the next memory. I didn't realize that Python lists treated it as a hash table.

Comment: No, Python `list`s are not hash tables, they're arrays. Python `set`s, `dict`s, and `Counter`s, however, are hash tables. That's why using a `Counter` is good here—you can do your lookups in O(1) time each, instead of the O(N) you'd have with an array (or a linked list).

Comment: @abarnert: Search times with a sorted array are only O(log n) on average with a binary search, so sometimes that's a viable alternate.

Comment: @martineau: Sure, but inserts into a sorted array are O(N), and he's doing as many inserts as searches, so that wouldn't help. You could use a balanced tree (e.g., from the `blist` module on PyPI), skip list, or other structure to get O(log N) for both inserts and searches, but not with a `list` or other array type structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really don't think you'll get better than a `collections.Counter` for this:

```
c = Counter(mylist)
duplicates = [ x for x,y in c.items() if y > 1 ]
```

building the Counter should be `O(n)` (unless you're using keys which are particularly bad for hashing -- But in my experience, you need to try pretty hard to make that happen) and then getting the duplicates list is also `O(n)` giving you a total complexity of `O(2n) == O(n)` (for typical uses).

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm mistaken by how the counter works, but I assumed (which I shouldn't) that it went down on the order of n + (n-1) + (n-2) ... + 1 --> n(n-1)/2; I might be mistaken though, if I am can you clarify how it works.

Comment: It holds the elements as a dictionary, so lookup is O(n)

Comment: @nair.ashvin: Lookup for n items is O(n). Lookup for each item is O(1). I think that distinction may be what confused the OP in the first place.

Comment: Thank you this clears it up, I was mistaken about the data structures in Python

Comment: @TTT -- Counters are dictionaries (hash tables).  Barring too many collisions, lookup is `O(1)` -- with `n` items, your cost to look up them all is approximately `O(n)`.